# Unable to create custom images in Vis.Js Network with React Typescript

Tags: react-typescript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am trying to have a custom node shape drawn up using the node.shape as custom and provide a ctxRenderer function. However, it seems that ctxRenderer is not supported as the Node class and NodeOptions class does not contain this function. I am currently version "vis-network": "^9.1.6". Is there any chance a different version of the Vis.Js package have this feature enabled?